# Exe file converted from python crashes after being opened

Tags: python, pyinstaller, exe

I'm having a problem with an exe file converted from .py: as I always do I used pyinstaller (`pyinstaller --onefile client.py`), but when I run the generated .exe file it closes just after opening. Of course the original .py file works perfectly.
This is the client.py file that I was trying to convert:

```
from email import message
import socket
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring
import threaded
from threading import Thread
import _thread
import os
import time

#Variable assignment
global string
global text
global rebooting
string = "string"
text = "text"
rebooting = False

hostname = socket.gethostname()
local_ip = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
ip = str(local_ip)
port = 55555

name = str(input("Insert your name: "))

#Message recived handling
def recive(server):
    global string
    global text
    global rebooting
    while True:
        try:
            text = server.recv(2024)
            text = text.decode('utf-8')
            if text == name + ": " + string:
                pass
            elif text == "!exit":
            pass
            elif text == "_reboot_": 
                server.close()
                rebooting = True
                break
            else:
                print(text)
        except:
            pass

def send(server):
    global string
    global text
    global rebooting
    server.send(bytes(name, "utf-8"))
    while True:
        try:
            string = str(input())
            if string == "!exit":
                server.send(bytes(string, "utf-8"))
                time.sleep(1)
                server.close()
                break
            elif rebooting == True:
                time.sleep(5)
                start()
                break
            else:
                #string = "string test"
                server.send(bytes(string, "utf-8"))
        except :
            pass

def start():
    global rebooting
    #Defining server
    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    server.connect((ip, port))
    rebooting = False
    #Strting client operations
    _thread.start_new_thread(recive ,(server,))
    send(server)

start()
```

I can't figure out if I am doing something wrong in the conversion command or if there is something in the .py code that generates an error.

Comment: run the `.exe` with the terminal and read what it says

Comment: Add a __main__ block ?

Comment: I ran the file in the terminal and it gives no errors and nothing else, it just opens for a split second and then closes.